# how to dot the relative path with arguments in powershell script

Tags: powershell, parameters, relative-path, dot-source

I have a header.ps1 file that need to be called from the Main.ps1 script. They are both under the same directory.

In the header.ps1 file, it started off with following...

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
[String]$PROJECTNAME =  'PSToolBox',
[string]$SCRIPTNAME = 'accountSelector.ps1'
)
```

In the Main.ps1 file, the following does work except I cannot use header.ps1 parameters.

This works:

```
. ($PSScriptRoot + '\header.ps1')
```

This does NOT work:

```
. (($PSScriptRoot + '\header.ps1') -PROJECTNAME 'LunchBox' -SCRIPTNAME 'MyLunch.ps1')
```

So, how to dot the relative path with passing the parameters in powershell script?

Comment: More streamlined, using string interpolation: `. "$PSScriptRoot\header.ps1" -PROJECTNAME 'LunchBox' -SCRIPTNAME 'MyLunch.ps1'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the command name/path separately from the parameter arguments (this applies not only to `.`, the same goes for invocations with `&`):

```
. ($PSScriptRoot + '\header.ps1') -PROJECTNAME 'LunchBox' -SCRIPTNAME 'MyLunch.ps1'
# \_____________________________/ \_______________________________________________/
#       first the command                     ... and then the arguments
```